# How to connect to Informix DB on host machine from a container through jdbc?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, containers, informix

Informix db 12.10 is installed and works fine to connect via a java application using informix jdbc, both are on host machine. When I use a docker container to run my java application and connect to Informix on host machine, it does not connect.

The docker0 on host machine shows 172.17.0.1 and ip of container is 172.17.0.2.

ping works between two IPs

is there any setting required to bind informix to 0.0.0.0 or to pass --host variable to container while starting it?

Answer (score 0):

Informix needs to listen on the IP through which you'd like to connect. In case Informix is listening only on `127.0.0.1`, you cannot connect through `172.17.0.1`.

One way to fix this is to configure Informix to listen on `0.0.0.0`. This way if you try to connect through docker0's `172.17.0.1`, it should work.